# mongodb any command instead of count

Tags: mongodb

I use

```
collection.count(query)
```

where `query` uses `gte` and `lte` commands.

It working ok. But not very fast.

Maybe it will be faster to use something like "`any`" command instead of `count`.

Is there any equivalent of

```
//pseudoCode
collection.any(query)
```

which should return `true` if `count > 0` and `false` if `count == 0`

I tried to use [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/). But seemingly it can be used only with single field, like

```
db.records.find( { b: { $exists: false } } )
```

and cannot be applied to `gte` `less` query like this

```
query
{
  "from_5": {
    "$lte": 79038
  },
  "to_5": {
    "$gte": 79038
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you actually asking? How about showing the full query you want even if your syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `find` or `findOne`... I'd use the former since it's said to be more efficient. And call `size()` on the cursor returned to get the number of documents.

So:

```
db.collection.find(query).limit(1).size()
```